# redirect to checkout if cart is not equal 1, redirect to home page else

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
function wpse_19692_registration_redirect() {
    if ( is_cart() && sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) == 0) { 
        return home_url('/'); 
    }else{
        return get_permalink( "https://learndigital-mena.com/checkout/" ); 
    }   
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_19692_registration_redirect' );
```

Hi every one .. Im using this code to redirect user who trying to register while the cart has elements inside it to the checkout page and if its empty I want it to redirect to the home page .. but its not working ): .. any idea? what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"return" is not using for redirect. It returns the information and stops the function call. You can use wp_redirect() function instead.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/